# Is there a way to do this query without the sub-select?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I'm not positive but I believe sub-selects are less than optimal (speedwise?).

Is there a way to remove this sub-select from my query (I think the query is self-explanatory).

```
select *
from tickers
where id = (select max(id) from tickers where annual_score is not null);
```

Comment: Also consider indexing.  Is `annual_score` indexed?  Is `id`?  If they both are, then that's probably about as fast as you're going to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That particular sub-select shouldn't be inefficient at all. It should be run *once* before the main query begins.

There are a certain class of subqueries that *are* inefficient (those that join columns between the main query and the subquery) because they end up running the subquery for every single row of the main query.

But this shouldn't be one of them, unless MySQL is severely brain-damaged, which I doubt.

However, if you remain keen to get rid of the subquery, you can order the rows by id (descending) and only fetch the first, something like:

```
select * from tickers
where annual_score is not null
order by id desc
limit 0, 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Would something like:

`SELECT *
FROM ticker
WHERE annual_score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 1`

work?

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with MySQL, but if you want to eliminate the subquery then you could try something like this:

```
select * 
from tickers
where annual_score is not null
order by id desc
limit 1
```

I don't know if this is more or less performant as MySQL is not my background.

Comment: Looks like someone else had the same idea.